# zsh: how to iterate files with asterix (`bla-*.zip`)

Tags: zsh

I have tried:

```
for f in bla-*.zip; do ... done
```

and:

```
for f (bla-*.zip) { ... }
```

In both cases, I get the error: `no matches found`. No such file exists, so of course it doesn't find any matches, but how can I make it work in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution ([here](https://serverfault.com/a/499596)). I can do:

```
for f in bla-*.zip(N); do ... done
```